# How do I jump to the opening or closing paren/brace/... in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Suppose my point is currently on or next to a opening or closing paren, brace or bracket. How can I jump to the respective matching counterpart?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in emacs wiki (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NavigatingParentheses):

- `C-M-n`     *forward-list*  Move forward over a parenthetical group
- `C-M-p`     *backward-list*  Move backward over a parenthetical
  group
- `C-M-f`     *forward-sexp* Move forward over a balanced expression
- `C-M-b`     *backward-sexp*  Move backward over a balanced
  expression
- `C-M-k`     *kill-sexp*  Kill balanced expression forward
- `C-M-SPC`   *mark-sexp*  Put the mark at the end of the sexp.